# Python 2 print functionality in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I learned that Python 3 print statements require parentheses, but I was told I could do:

```
from __past__ import print
```

but this doesn't seem to work. It gives me an error

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Full code:

```
from __past__ import print

print 'hello'
```

Comment: Umm, doesn't executing this code throw an ImportError on your machine? Because it should.

Comment: Why would you want to achieve this regardless of whether it is possible or not?

Comment: one more urban legend

Comment: you can also try: `from __prehistory__ import perl`

Comment: Since `from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL` worked, I tried `from __past__ import guido_as_BDFL`, but it just said `ImportError: People won't shut up about PEP 572`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But `from __prehistory__ import tcl` works, you just have to spell it `import tkinter`. :P

Comment: :) that one made my day.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Assuming this is a script, the SyntaxError happens first, because it happens at parse time. (In interactive mode, the ImportError happens first, because the import is parsed and executed before Python sees the bad `print` line.)

Answer (score 3):

`from __past__ import print` isn't a real thing. Perhaps you misunderstood a joke, or someone lied to you. Whatever the case may be, you'll have to get used to `print` being a function, because there's no toggle to bring back the statement.

Comment: aprils fool probably.

Comment: Why is this a "community wiki"?

Comment: because someone doesn't want rep from that, and kudos for that.